# Verfiy the number of times a cuda kernel is called

Tags: c++, cuda

Say you have a cuda kernel that you want to run 2048 times, so you define your kernel like this:

```
__global__ void run2048Times(){ }
```

Then you call it from your main code:

```
run2048Times<<<2,1024>>>();
```

All seems well so far. However now say for debugging purposes when you're calling the kernel millions of times, you want to verify that your actually calling the Kernel that many times.

What I did was pass a pointer to the kernel and ++'d the pointer every time the kernel ran.

```
__global__ void run2048Times(int *kernelCount){ 
    kernelCount[0]++; // Add to the pointer
}
```

However when I copied that pointer back to the main function I get "2".

At first it baffeled me, then after 5 minutes of coffee and pacing back and forth I realized this probably makes sense because the cuda kernel is running 1024 instances of itself at the same time, which means that the kernels overwrite the "kernelCount[0]" instead of truly adding to it.

So instead I decided to do this:

```
__global__ void run2048Times(int *kernelCount){

   // Get the id of the kernel
   int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

   // If the id is bigger than the pointer overwrite it
   if(id > kernelCount[0]){
        kernelCount[0] = id; 
   }
}
```

Genius!! This was guaranteed to work I thought. Until I ran it and got all sorts of numbers between 0 and 2000.

Which tells me that the problem mentioned above still happens here.

Is there any way to do this, even if it involves forcing the kernels to pause and wait for each other to run?

Comment: That sounds like a job for profiling....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a simplified example, and you are not in fact trying to do profiling as others have already suggested, but want to use this in a more complex scenario, you can achieve the result you want with [`atomicAdd`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions), which will ensure that the increment operation is executed as a single *atomic* operation:

```
__global__ void run2048Times(int *kernelCount){ 
    atomicAdd(kernelCount, 1); // Add to the pointer
}
```

### Why your solutions didn't work:

The problem with your first solution is that it gets compiled into the following PTX code (see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) for description of PTX instructions):

```
ld.global.u32   %r1, [%rd2];
add.s32     %r2, %r1, 1;
st.global.u32   [%rd2], %r2;
```

You can verify this by calling `nvcc` with the `--ptx` option to only generate the intermediate representation.

What can happen here is the following timeline, assuming you launch 2 threads (**Note:** this is a simplified example and not exactly how GPUs work, but it is enough to illustrate the problem):

1. thread `0` reads `0` from `kernelCount`
2. thread `1` reads `0` from `kernelCount`
3. thread `0` increases it's local copy by `1`
4. thread `0` stores `1` back to `kernelCount`
5. thread `1` increases it's local copy by `1`
6. thread `1` stores `1` back to `kernelCount`

and you end up with `1` even though 2 threads were launched.

Your second solution is wrong even if the threads are launched sequentially because thread indexes are 0-based. So I'll assume you wanted to do this:

```
__global__ void run2048Times(int *kernelCount){

   // Get the id of the kernel
   int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

   // If the id is bigger than the pointer overwrite it
   if(id + 1 > kernelCount[0]){
        kernelCount[0] = id + 1; 
   }
}
```

This will compile into:

```
    ld.global.u32   %r5, [%rd1];
    setp.lt.s32 %p1, %r1, %r5;
    @%p1 bra    BB0_2;

    add.s32     %r6, %r1, 1;
    st.global.u32   [%rd1], %r6;

BB0_2:
    ret;
```

What can happen here is the following timeline:

1. thread `0` reads `0` from `kernelCount`
2. thread `1` reads `0` from `kernelCount`
3. thread `1` compares `0` to `1 + 1` and stores `2` into `kernelCount`
4. thread `0` compares `0` to `0 + 1` and stores `1` into `kernelCount`

You end up having the wrong result of 1.

I suggest you pick up a good parallel programming / CUDA book if you want to better understand problems with synchronization and non-atomic operations.

*EDIT*:

For completeness, the version using `atomicAdd` compiles into:

```
    atom.global.add.u32     %r1, [%rd2], 1;
```

Comment: You are awesome, this answer went well and above what my question deserved. Thank you so much! This helped me understand majorly what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the only point of that counter is to do profiling (i.e. analyse how the code runs) rather than to actually count something (i.e. no functional benefit to the program).

There are profiling tools available designed for this task. For example, [nvprof](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html) gives the number of calls, as well as some time metrics for each kernel in your codebase.

Comment: Awesome thank you! It looks like I've got a lot of reading to do and stuff to learn.